# Event bubbles before captured on `window`

Tags: javascript

```html
<html>
<div id="block"></div>
<script>
    window.id = 'window'
    const targets = [window, document.querySelector('#block')]
    for (const target of targets) {
        target.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            console.log(`\tbubble: ${target.id}, evnetPhase: ${e.eventPhase}`)
        })
        target.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            console.log(`\tcapture: ${target.id}, evnetPhase: ${e.eventPhase}`)
        }, true)
    }

    console.log('dispatch on block:')
    targets[1].dispatchEvent(new Event('click'))
    console.log('==================================================')
    console.log('dispatch on window:')
    window.dispatchEvent(new Event('click'))
    console.log('==================================================')
</script>
</html>
```

Result:

```
dispatch on block:
    capture: window, evnetPhase: 1      <- ok
    capture: block, evnetPhase: 2
    bubble: block, evnetPhase: 2
==================================================
dispatch on window:
    bubble: window, evnetPhase: 2       <- bubble before capture?
    capture: window, evnetPhase: 2
==================================================
```

But if you click the webpage with the mouse to dispatch a real `click` event, the order is right.

```
real click:
    capture: window, evnetPhase: 1
    bubble: window, evnetPhase: 3
```

Other types of events are the same as `click`, including `CustomEvent`.

How can I get the right order with `window.dispatchEvent(evt)`?

Comment: What is the right order? Why do you expect `capture` before `bubble`?

Comment: Yes, `capture` before `bubble`, just as the same by clicking the webpage. @jabaa

Comment: Why do you expect this behavior? I tried your code. I expect `bubble` before `capture` and that's what I get. The `bubble` listener is registered first.

Comment: Chrome/Chromium and Firefox seem to behave differently with different order in the `dispatch on block` case. It seem like either the order is not specified or one these both browsers has a bug.

Comment: For reference, a visual representation of the DOM event flow: https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-flow . Event handles bound to the *target* element are executed in the "target" phase, so the capture flag is irrelevant.

Comment: What's the actual problem you trying to solve here? There might not be a general solution to this problem but if we know what you are trying to achieve there might be alternative approaches.

Comment: @FelixKling OK, I've figured out what's going on here. It seems I have to change to an alternative solution to solve the problem in my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the actual `eventPhase` of the event, you'll see that the event is always in the AT_TARGET (`2`) phase when firing on the `window` object.

There is no bubbling involved, so `capture` option has no effect and the order when the event handlers were attached is what will determine when they'll fire.

However, there is a special casing that [got introduced](https://github.com/whatwg/dom/pull/686) relatively recently (2019) for reordering capturing handlers before non-capturing ones on events that do bubble. [Firefox still didn't catch up on this change](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1492446).

So to always get the capturing event handlers to fire before the non-capturing one, attach them first.

Comment: _"the order when the event handlers were attached is what will determine when they'll fire."_ That's not true. Firefox and Chrome fire in different order and the functions in the question are fired in reversed order. `capture: block, evnetPhase: 2` is printed before `bubble: block, evnetPhase: 2` and I can reproduce it in Chrome.

Comment: @jabaa that would be a browser bug. Which browser doesn't follow the order?

Comment: @jabaa For me both FF and Chrome output the same: https://jsfiddle.net/9pm4gzsf/

Comment: OP's browser and Google Chrome 94.0.4606.61 on Linux.

Comment: OP's log outputs bubble first then capture, i.e the order they did add the event listeners.

Comment: My output with Google Chrome and OP's output of your jsfiddle: `"dispatch on block:"
"   capture: undefined, evnetPhase: 1"
"   capture: block, evnetPhase: 2"
"   bubble: block, evnetPhase: 2"
"=================================================="
"dispatch on window:"
"   bubble: undefined, evnetPhase: 2"
"   capture: undefined, evnetPhase: 2"
"=================================================="`

Comment: My output with Firefox: `"dispatch on block:"
"   capture: undefined, evnetPhase: 1"
"   bubble: block, evnetPhase: 2"
"   capture: block, evnetPhase: 2"
"=================================================="
"dispatch on window:"
"   bubble: undefined, evnetPhase: 2"
"   capture: undefined, evnetPhase: 2"
"=================================================="`

Comment: Yes, so bubble first then capture, the order we added the listeners...

Comment: @jabaa and what is different in both?

Comment: In the first output you have `"   capture: block, evnetPhase: 2" "   bubble: block, evnetPhase: 2"` and in the second `"   bubble: block, evnetPhase: 2" "   capture: block, evnetPhase: 2"`. You see `capture` first and then `bubble`, reversed order of registration.

Comment: ... I guess you are confused by your logs... Please read them again thoroughly (note that the most important one is the one after "dispatch on window:"

Comment: So the behavior of `dispatchEvent` on `window` is special? Is there any document that mentions this? When dispatching events on a DOM node like `block`, the order is `capture + phase 2`, `bubble + phase 2`.

Comment: _"note that the most important one is the one after "dispatch on window:""_ Why? The question is why the first order is different than the second. A dispatch on block triggers `capture` first and `bubble` next. A dispatch on window triggers `bubble` first and `capture` next. And why is it different in Firefox and Chrome? Which one has the correct order?

Comment: @user16833022 it's not only `dispatchEvent`, it's any event that will fire on the window object. I thought I saw a note in the specs, but I can't find it anymore, maybe I dreamed of it... But by the logic of [event invocation](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-event-listener-inner-invoke), that's just expected: there is nothing on top of window in the target chain, so you start at AT_TARGET, so capture is ignored both in step 2.3 and 2.4

Comment: @jabaa because the special case is the one on `window`.

Comment: This https://imgur.com/a/qFt4Gk1 doesn't look like the exact same behavior in Firefox and Chrome. Left-hand side is Chrome and right-hand side is Firefox. Which order is correct according to the specs?

Comment: And how does this answer the question _"How can I get the right order with `window.dispatchEvent(evt)`?"_ It only explains the current behavior but doesn't contain a solution. Different browsers fire in different order.

Comment: ok, ok, I only now see the discrepancy when the event fires on "#block". So the issue is actually quite new (https://crbug.com/1052152) and it **was** working the way I stated But it seems this did change and [Firefox hasn't caught up yet.](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1492446)

Comment: @Kaiido:  Great findings! the tl;dr: Event handlers used to be called in registration order in the target phase, but that could expose the existence of shadow DOM, so they decided to call capture event handlers first, but changes can take time in the browser world.